# Cross Linux-Flavor Method - List all fonts

Tags: xorg, fonts

I was trying to use x11, or file system, to get a list of all the installed fonts on the system. Is there a cross linux-flavor method to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the `fc-list` command to list all the fonts the logged in user can use.

Comment: Thanks very much. Does fc-list use x11 internally?

Comment: No. fc-list is a tool of the fontconfig project, and is what most, if not all, modern toolkits use for finding fonts on the system.